# Unit Test for overwrite collection class in magento2

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

Suppose I overwrite 'Magento\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Collection' to 'SR\RewriteSales\Model\Resource\Order\Collection', code looks like

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        // custom condition applied here

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
```

Now I need some test case for 'AddFieldToFilter' method.

I create a file inside SR\RewriteSales\Test\Unit\Model\Resource\Order\CollectionTest.php
code looks like

```
class CollectionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Collection|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Select|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    protected $select;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->select = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\DB\Select')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $connection = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $connection->expects($this->any())
            ->method('select')
            ->will($this->returnValue($this->select));

        $resource = $this->getMockBuilder('Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['__wakeup', 'getReadConnection'])
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();
        $resource->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getReadConnection')
            ->will($this->returnValue($connection));

        $objectManagerHelper = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
        $arguments = $objectManagerHelper->getConstructArguments(
            'SR\RewriteSales\Model\Resource\Order\Collection',
            ['resource' => $resource, 'connection' => $connection]
        );

        $this->collection = $this->getMockBuilder('SR\RewriteSales\Model\Resource\Order\Collection')
            ->setConstructorArgs($arguments)
            ->setMethods(['addFilter', '_translateCondition', 'getMainTable', '__wakeup'])
            ->getMock();
    }

    public function testAddFieldToFilter()
    {

    }
}
```

It's come following error-> "RuntimeException: ObjectManager isn't initialized".

Is that possible to create some test case for overwrite class?

Comment: Do you use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() method in your code?

Answer (score 3):

First of all better to do not mock class under test.

Second one, better to use plugins instead of class overwrite.

And last, you must pass all parameters of parent constructor to your class.

Simplest way to instantiate class is using objectMangerHelper

```
    $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
    $this->collection = $objectManager->getObject(
        'SR\RewriteSales\Model\Resource\Order\Collection',
        [
            'resource' => $resource, 
            'connection' => $connection,

        ]
    );
```

Comment: So can you give some example or update my question ?

Comment: Same error 'testAddFieldToFilter RuntimeException: ObjectManager isn't initialized'

Comment: Please try to add '__wakeup' to list of method to mock: ->setMethods(['addFilter', '_translateCondition', 'getMainTable', '__wakeup' ])

Comment: No luck, same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you use `phpunit.xml` from `dev/tests/unit/` dir?
Also you shouldn't mock class which you want test (@KAndy comment said about that)

Comment: yes. I am using phpunit.xml from dev/tests/unit/ dir.